# Is there a way to estimate the shape or curvature of a function given some data points?

Tags: function, parameters, curve-fitting, prediction, shapes

I have a series of measurements (data points), we can call them Ys for now, and two input variables m and n, such that f(m,n) = Y. Is there an easy way to compute the shape or curvature for function f that maps m,n into Ys - i.e., determining whether the function is polynomial or something else? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Julia, welcome. Your question is quite general such that it is unlikely to get a reasonable answer. You should try to be more specific and maybe even try to provide some code with according data. Apart from this. You can always find a high order polynomial to fit a finite set of points. The question here is whether or not this makes sense. Hence, you need criteria to decide what function is reasonable. So you should probably provide a list of reasonable function. In that case there are definitively methods to decide which one fits best.

Comment: Hello, this is exactly what I am trying to do - find a high order polynomial to fit my data, without knowing the function. Would you be able to guide me towards an example, please? Has this been asked before? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Julia. The problem is: If you chose the order high enough, you can always ensure perfect fit. Most of the time, this does not make sense, though, as the values between data strongly fluctuate. You usually need a certain smoothness of you function. Maybe you should have a look at splines. This is a generic way of fitting data.